# Laptop screen is cracked, external monitor only mirroring the broken laptop screen

Tags: laptop, display, external-display

I did something stupid. When my Dell Vostro 1000 laptop screen cracked and went all crazy and I couldn't see anything, I attached it to an external monitor and pressed <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> and it worked.

But then I did something in the control panel that made the external screen look similar to the laptop screen. That made the external screen completely unusable too. In the control panel it was the last tab – something with "dual screens" I think.

Is there anyway to reverse what did, turn off the laptop screen permanently and turn the external monitor into the primary?

Remember that I can't see anything on the laptop screen. It is a complete goner – and because of what I did I can't see anything on the external monitor.

Comment: Try booting into safe mode with the monitor attached. If you can't see it on boot to hit F8, you may need to hit the Fn+F5 a couple more times. There may also be something in your BIOS settings to make the external monitor the primary.

Comment: what are BIOS settings

Comment: I saw this an answer to a similar question given by kez              the Question: http://superuser.com/q/282393/92415

Comment: I saw an answer to a similar question given by kez -              the Question: http://superuser.com/q/282393/92415  the answer was - 
Press Win+R to bring up the Run dialog box.

Type control desk.cpl and click OK to open the display properties box on the screen that you cannot see.

Press Alt+Space to bring up a special menu.

Press M to put the window into "move! dammit!" mode.

Now use the left or right arrow key, keep tapping it or hold it down until the window appears on your working screen. ** once i get to step 4 it doesnt apply but is there anyway to cont. w/ this using the key board?

Answer (score 1):

Most of laptops will go to external monitor if their lid is closed (e.g. so you can use it closed in docking station).

Most laptops have micro switch on monitor hinges. Press that switch (and keep it pressed) in order for laptop to think it's lid is closed and your external monitor will become you primary (and only) screen.